# Mongod refueses to start on macos, giving a long and cryptic error message

Tags: mongodb

So I'm trying to a start up a mongodb background process (for a personal project) on macos. And I installed it to my computer using these steps [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). I've followed all the steps correctly, by tapping it and installing it on the homebrew package manager. Everything installs correctly, but when I type `sudo mongod` into terminal, I get this message here:

```
        {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T18:17:12.908-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T18:17:12.913-07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
```

And the at the end there is this message here:

```
  84931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T18:19:18.868-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T18:19:18.868-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

I didn't want to annoy you guys with the whole error message in this post, so I put the error in a pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/hH21AmjY. I tried reinstalling everything with sudo, logging in or out, checking privacy in system preferences. However, I'm new to mongo, so I don't understand this big mess of gibberish.

Comment: The link you had posted has this step to start the `mongod`: [Run MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb-community-edition)

Answer (score 1):

The important part is this:

> NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file.